# React Native Video Player Video Controls - Problem with changing the video orientation using the fullscreen button

Tags: android, react-native, button, video, screen-orientation

I use react-native-video-controls. I have a problem with the button from full screen when autorotate is enable. While watching a video, I can change the position of the phone to landscape, but the full screen arrows do not change the status. Then, to change the view to portrait with the button you have to double-click on it, because the arrow still showed that you can change to landscape.

Is there any way for the event to listen for a change of orientation?

Events in the VideoPlayer component **onEnterFullscreen** and **onExitFullscreen**.

```
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-controls';

const VideoContainer = props => {
  const {content} = props;
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    rate: 1,
    volume: 1,
    muted: false,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    duration: 0.0,
    currentTime: 0.0,
    paused: false,
    hideControls: false,
    controlText: 'Pause',
    fullScreen: false,
    isBuffering: true,
  });

  const [video, setVideo] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const deviceIsTilted = useSelector(
    ({globalReducer}) => globalReducer.deviceIsTilted,
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (video)
      deviceIsTilted ? setFullScreenState(true) : setFullScreenState(false);
    return () => {
      Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
      dispatch(setFullScreenStateAction(false));
    };
  }, [video, deviceIsTilted]);

  const onLoad = ({duration}) =>
    setOptions(prev => ({...prev, duration, isBuffering: false}));

  const onProgress = ({currentTime}) =>
    setOptions(prev => ({...prev, currentTime}));

  const onEnd = () => {
    const controlText = options.paused ? 'Pause' : 'Play';
    setOptions(prev => ({...prev, paused: true, controlText}));
  };

  const onBuffer = ({isBuffering}) =>
    setOptions(prev => ({...prev, isBuffering}));

  const setFullScreenState = state => {
    dispatch(setFullScreenStateAction(state));
    setOptions(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      fullScreen: state,
      resizeMode: state ? 'stretch' : 'contain',
    }));

    state ? lockScreenToLandscape() : unlockScreen();
  };

  const lockScreenToLandscape = () => {
    Orientation.lockToLandscape();
  };

  const unlockScreen = () => {
    Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
  };

  const onPressVideo = () => videoCallback();

  const onPressBtnPlay = () => videoCallback();

  const onPressSliderBtnPlay = () => {
    setOptions(prev => ({...prev, paused: false, controlText: 'Pause'}));
  };

  const onPressSliderBtnPause = () => {
    setOptions(prev => ({...prev, paused: true, controlText: 'Play'}));
  };

  const videoCallback = () => {
    const controlText = options.paused ? 'Pause' : 'Play';
    setOptions(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      paused: !prev.paused,
      controlText,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <Card
      style={
        options.fullScreen
          ? [styles.fullScreenContainer, styles.fullScreen]
          : styles.container
      }>
      <Card.Content
        style={options.fullScreen ? styles.fullScreen : styles.defaultScreen}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPressVideo}>
          <VideoPlayer
            ref={ref => setVideo(ref)}
            source={{
              uri: content.data,
            }}
            style={
              options.fullScreen ? styles.fullScreen : styles.defaultScreen
            }
            rate={options.rate}
            paused={options.paused}
            volume={options.volume}
            muted={options.muted}
            resizeMode={options.resizeMode}
            fullScreen={options.fullScreen}
            toggleResizeModeOnFullscreen={false}
            onEnterFullscreen={() => setFullScreenState(true)}
            onExitFullscreen={() => setFullScreenState(false)}
            onLoad={onLoad}
            onProgress={onProgress}
            onPlay={onPressSliderBtnPlay}
            onPause={onPressSliderBtnPause}
            onEnd={onEnd}
            onBuffer={onBuffer}
            repeat={true}
            title={content.title}
            tapAnywhereToPause={true}
            controlTimeout={4500}
            disableVolume
            disableBack
          />
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <KeepAwake />
        {options.isBuffering ? (
          options.fullScreen ? (
            <ActivityIndicator
              size="large"
              color="#757575"
              style={styles.spinnerFullScreen}
            />
          ) : (
            <>
              <ActivityIndicator
                size="large"
                color="#757575"
                style={styles.spinner}
              />
            </>
          )
        ) : null}
      </Card.Content>
      <View
        style={
          options.fullScreen
            ? [styles.progressBarDefault, styles.progressBarFullScreen]
            : styles.progressBarDefault
        }
      />
      {!options.fullScreen && (
        <View style={styles.controls}>
          <View style={styles.playControl}>
            <Button
              style={styles.controlBtn}
              onPress={onPressBtnPlay}
              mode="contained"
              color={Colors.blue700}>
              {options.controlText}
            </Button>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
    </Card>
  );
};
```